# Realm can't create Nested Objects from Json

Tags: java, android, json, realm

I've been trying to create a nested RealmObject using a json but it only creates the first Object and not the nested ones. I would appreciate a help on this.

my Realm classes:

Content.java

```
public class Content extends RealmObject {
    private String uuid;
    RealmList<ContentDetailModel> ContentDetail;

    public Content() {
        super();
        this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public RealmList<ContentDetailModel> getContentDetails() {
        return ContentDetail;
    }

    public void setContentDetails(RealmList<ContentDetailModel> contentDetails) {
        this.ContentDetail = contentDetails;
    }
}
```

ContentDetailModel.java:

```
public class ContentDetailModel extends RealmObject {
    String FileName;
    String ContentTypeID;
    RealmList<ContentDetailMetadataModel> ContentDetailMetadata;
    RealmResults<Content> content = null;
    public String getFileName() {
        return FileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        FileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getContentTypeID() {
        return ContentTypeID;
    }

    public void setContentTypeID(String contentTypeID) {
        ContentTypeID = contentTypeID;
    }

    public RealmList<ContentDetailMetadataModel> getContentDetailMetadata() {
        return ContentDetailMetadata;
    }

    public void setContentDetailMetadata(RealmList<ContentDetailMetadataModel> contentDetailMetadataz) {
        this.ContentDetailMetadata = contentDetailMetadataz;
    }
}
```

and the rest of nested classes are like these. my Json string is as follows:

"

```
{
   "Content":{
      "ContentDetail":[
         {
            "FileName":"test.mp3",
            "ContentTypeID":3,
            "ContentDetailMetadata":{
               "Metadata":[
                  {
                     "ID":2,
                     "Value":"2017-08-02 09:40:30"
                  },
                  {
                     "ID":1,
                     "Value":"35.73876557934912,51.50785446166992"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "FileName":"2.jpg",
            "ContentTypeID":2,
            "ContentDetailMetadata":[
               {
                  "Metadata":{
                     "ID":2,
                     "Value":"2017-08-02 09:40:30"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "Metadata":{
                     "ID":1,
                     "Value":"35.73876557934912,51.50785446166992"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

"

and the code I use to do it is :

```
realm.createObjectFromJson(json)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
   "Content":{
      "ContentDetail":[
         {
            "FileName":"test.mp3",
            "ContentTypeID":3,
            "ContentDetailMetadata":[{
               "Metadata":[
                  {
                     "ID":2,
                     "Value":"2017-08-02 09:40:30"
                  },
                  {
                     "ID":1,
                     "Value":"35.73876557934912,51.50785446166992"
                  }
               ]
            }]
         },
```

Translates to:

```
public class Root extends RealmObject {
    private Content Content;
}

public class Content extends RealmObject {
    private RealmList<ContentDetail> ContentDetail;

    @LinkingObjects("Content") 
    private final RealmResults<Root> roots = null;
}

public class ContentDetail extends RealmObject {
    private String FileName;
    private long ContentTypeID;
    //private ContentDetailMetadata ContentDetailMetadata;
    private RealmList<ContentDetailMetadata> ContentDetailMetadata;

    @LinkingObjects("ContentDetail") 
    private final RealmResults<Content> contents = null;
}

public class ContentDetailMetadata extends RealmObject {
    private RealmList<Metadata> Metadata;

    @LinkingObjects("ContentDetailMetadata") 
    private final RealmResults<ContentDetail> contentDetails = null;
}

public class Metadata extends RealmObject {
    private long ID;
    private String Value;

    @LinkingObjects("Metadata") 
    private final RealmResults<ContentDetailMetadata> contentDetailMetadatas = null;
}
```

If your schema doesn't look like that, then `createOrUpdateFromJson()` won't work.

Personally I would advise against using this schema though, it's pretty bad as a Realm schema. It's advisable to parse the JSON and then map it into a schema that makes more sense!

Comment: ` io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not map JSON` it seems your answer is a step closer to the answer but I get exception yet.

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: ` io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not map JSON`

Comment: anything more specific in the stack trace somewhere? o-o

Comment: `realm.createObjectFromJson(Root.class, testXmlToJson());` gives Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"Metadata":{"ID":2,"Value":"2017-08-02 09:40:30"}},{"Metadata":{"ID":1,"Value":"35.73876557934912,51.50785446166992"}}] at ContentDetailMetadata of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: ***wooooooooooow*** i didn't notice that `"ContentDetailMetadata":{` can **also be** `"ContentDetailMetadata":[{` what a terrible api. It should either be a JsonObject or a JsonArray, not both! -_- I'm not even sure if this is by default compatible with any JSON parsers without manually deserializing.

Comment: Actually it's an XML response I get and I want to map it to JSON and then use Realm :(.

Comment: The JSON shouldn't have inconsistent field. It must be either JSONArray or JSONObject, but it shouldn't be both. I changed my answer to assume JSONArray.

Comment: Yeah I know that, I changed it before you do and sadly that won't solve the problem, the cause of problem is how the XML file is presented and when I map it to Json all nodes except Content that is always one of it can be either JsonObject or JsonArray :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your JSON has put all fields for the `Content` object under the `Context` JSON object instead of directly under the top-level object where it should be.

If you do this, it should work:

```
realm.createObjectFromJson(Content.class, json.getJSONObject("Content"));
```

Comment: You also have other issues with your JSON, e.g `ContentDetailMetadata` is an object, not a `RealmList`.

Comment: That was not the case either, I tried with only Content and one contentDetail  in json and it didn't work again.

Comment: {"Content":{"ContentDetail":{"FileName":"test.mp3","ContentTypeID":3}}}

Comment: My actual code in activity is in kotlin, maybe this is the cause? `realm.createObjectFromJson(Content::class.java, testXmlToJson())`

Comment: okay I added a dummy String field to `Content` both in realm and jsonObject and it seems that Realm can't recognize fields of JsonObject except the Content. what's your guess?

Comment: and I'm using `org.json.*` to convert an XML file to Json

Comment: In your RealmModel `ContentDetail` is a List, not an Object, which is why it is being ignored. I actually thought we throw an exception in that case though.

Comment: No it must be a List because `ContentDetail` is jsonArray, as I said I added a property in JsonObject to the `Content`, a String named `alaki` and did the same in realmObject, what I witnessed is that realm can't find the fields of JsonObject. do u have any idea about this?

Comment: It is an object in the comment you posted above, not a List. It is a List in your post though. If you can isolate the problem in an example project, please create an issue at https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues. Then we can take a closer look